# Appending strings within a loop objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a for-in loop running unknown num of times, when its finished running I want to have all names appending like so: `name1, name2,name3` and so on.

How do I append the strings within the loop ?

I was thinking of something like this :

```
if (donePressed)
{
    NSString *allFriends;
    selectedFriends = friendPicker.selection;
    for (NSDictionary * friend in selectedFriends)
    {
        NSString * friendName = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
        // some built-in method that appends friendName to allFriends with a ", " between them
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",selectedFriends);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *allFriends = [[friendPicker.selection valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Comment: Nice answer, I should have reloaded the page :-)

Comment: @JustinAmberson OP will probably end up with something closer to your code the first time an entity has a `NULL` `name`.   My code is a bit fragile in its terseness.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
NSMutableString *nameString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
for loop (...) {
    NSString *currentName = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
    [nameString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ",currentName]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",nameString);
```

The answer above mine looks better, that function probably doesn't leave a trailing `,` at the end of the list. Mine would have to use `NSMakeRange()` to trim the trailing comma.